# C++ chart series name from variable

Tags: c++, vector, charts

I have a vector `vector<string> headers;` and for each header I want to add a new series to a chart control.

But my code doesn't work:

```
for (int i = 0; i < headers.size(); i++){
    DataVisual_V2::MainForm::chart_data->Series->Add(headers[i]);
}
```

It gives the error:

IntelliSense: function "System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::SeriesCollection::Add" cannot be called with the given argument list 
argument types are: (std::string)
            object type is: System::Windows::Forms::DataVisualization::Charting::SeriesCollection

Any idea what could be the problem?

thanks

Benjamin

Answer (score 0):

This function expects a parameter of `System::String` type, not `std::string`. `System::String` has a constructor that takes `char*`, so you can use

```
DataVisual_V2::MainForm::chart_data->Series->Add(String(headers[i].c_str()));
```

Comment: That didn't quite do the job. However, I changed my vector to `vector<System::String> headers` and now it works.
Thank you!